# automatically click cancel button while i shutdown though program in perl

Tags: perl

I wrote program to shutdown system automatically in PERL , while shutdown if we open any file the windows asked that the file will save or cancel , my aim is cancel button automatically clicked and shut the system

Answer (score 1):

Use the shutdown command - open up a cmd window and use shutdown /? to see help on it. When used by itself with no arguments, it will pop up a 30 second warning and then shut down the machine. It will ignore anything like dialogue boxes asking questions